# Why I am not able to get token for sandbox?

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, webservices, sandbox, security-token

I'm trying to get an access token for sandbox mode.

My post request:

```
{
"clientId": "xxxxxxxxxx",
"clientSecret": "xxxxxxx"
}
```

I'm sending the request to https://auth-test.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken according to documentation, but I get an unauthorized response:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthorized",
    "errorcode": 1,
    "documentation": ""
}
```

If I send the same request to https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken I get an access token succesfully for the production environment.

Am I missing something? I'm not a salesforce developer, but I'll need to build a web service that uses these api. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The auth-test is for "Production Support" instances, (when you login to the mc is your login url mc.test.exacttarget.com) and you need to create the package in that instance.

These are legacy sandbox environments. The same clientid/secret wouldn't work on both endpoints

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll check it with the marketing cloud team, since I was just provided with the client id and client secret.